# Parent and child relation code and display only first child list

Tags: archives, categories

```
for Indoor
-for bedroom
--TFL
---8u
---9u
--MFL
---10u
---11u
-for Kitchen
--ABC
---4u
---5u
--XYZ
---6u
---7u
```

These are the category listing...

when user click on the for bedroom at that time show only TFL and MFL and same when click for kitchen at that time show only xyz and abc...

and then

user click on TFL at that time show only 8u and 9u same user click on xyz at that time show only 4u and 5u...

this all are category listing

===========================

```
<?php
$vnkings_id = get_queried_object()->term_id;
$term_id = $vnkings_id; // id của term cha vừa tìm 
$taxonomy_name = 'product-category'; // post type của bạn, ví dụ products
$termchildren = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy_name );

echo '<ul>';
foreach ( $termchildren as $child ) {
    $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name );
    echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $child, $taxonomy_name ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
?>
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: I want this type of when user click on the for bedroom at that time show only TFL and MFL and same when click for kitchen at that time show only xyz and abc...

and then

user click on TFL at that time show only 8u and 9u same user click on xyz at that time show only 4u and 5u... 

but not work this code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [`get_term_children`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_children) you are retrieving a flat array of all child terms. What you want is an array with only the first child terms. Unfortunately there is no immediate way to retrieve this, so it has to be done in two steps:

```
$parent_term = get_term_by('slug', 'bedroom', 'your_taxonomy_slug');
```

This gives you the 'bedroom' taxonomy term. Now you can use this to find the direct children:

```
$children = get_terms( 'your_taxonomy_slug', array( 'parent' => $parent_term->term_id ) );
```

This returns an array of child terms.